# TypeScript error when passing untyped string to React component with typed props?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have an Icon component:

```
type Props = {
  icon:
    | "one"
    | "two";
}

const Icon: React.FC<Props> = ({ icon }) => {
    // generate icon
}
```

If I use it in another component with a hard coded value everything is fine:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
    return(
        <div>
            <Icon icon="one" />
        </div>
    )
}
```

However when it's set dynamically from props I get a TypeScript error, even when the icon is displayed correctly:

```
type Props = {
    icon?: string;
};

const MyComponent: React.FC<Props> = ({ icon }) => {
    return(
        <div>
        {
            icon && <Icon icon={icon} />
        }
        </div>
    )
}
```

> TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"one" | "two".
>
> index.tsx(8, 3): The expected type comes from property 'icon' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props & { children?: ReactNode; }'

Is this because TypeScript doesn't know that the string value passed will be either "one" or "two"?

If so then the only solution I can think of would be to export "one" and "two" as an enum. However this would make the component annoying to use as you'd always have to import this enum, rather than just pass the string that you want. Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: For myComponent you have defined `type Props = {
    icon?: string;
};
` instead your should use `type Props = {
    icon?: "one" | "two";
};
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Props in component have union values only that is one or two but where you are using the component its data type is defined by optional string variable so it's a mismatch

```
type Props = {
  icon:
    | "one"
    | "two";
}


type Props = {
    icon?: string;
};
```

To fix it you need to make both of these consistent

```
type Props = {
    icon?: "one"|"two";
};
```